# Autofac construction order with Web API Filters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have an authentication filter `IAutofacAuthenticationFilter` hooked up with a web api project.  The app uses basic auth for each request, and I want to construct a ClaimsPrincipal based upon the values int he Authorize header.

I also want to construct an object that depends upon the values in the ClaimsPrincipal.  The problem I'm running in to is that the controller is constructed (and thus the dependencies) before the filter, and the filter has not constructed the ClaimsPrincipal, and the controller dependencies fail to activate correctly without the ClaimsPrincipal.

Is there any way to specify the order here, or ensure that the filters run completely prior to the controller construction?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run something before the controller construction you can implement a `DelegatingHandler` http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkeyj.jpg

Comment: Are the principals needed before the controller action execution. Authentication Filters are executed after controller creation but before action invocation. You can construct the principals in the `AuthenticateAsync` Method of `IAuthenticationFilter` and then set the principal of the current thread and http context. You will then be able to access the user the the controller action via the `ApiController.User`